# What do encodings represent in node:stream?

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I'm creating a `Transform` stream to alter the output from a `Readable` stream before sending it to a `Writable` stream: `childProcess.stdout.pipe(transform).pipe(process.stdout)`.

However, I'm having difficulty understanding how encodings are meant to be used with streams, to the point that much of it seems directly opposite what I would expect. In particular, when my `transform()` method receives a chunk which is a `Buffer`, the specified encoding is always `"buffer"`, while string chunks can have any of a number of encodings.

But… isn't that backwards? Strings are meant to represent sequences of *characters* (stored in memory as UCS-2/UTF-16/ish, sure, but *conceptually* just code points) whereas buffers are sequences of *bytes*. Characters can be encoded as bytes, so a string needs *en*coded to become a buffer and a buffer needs *de*coded to become a string. Therefore, shouldn't buffers have encodings (if they're meant to represent character data at all) while strings should not?

Yet when receiving a buffer from a stream, I don't get told what encoding was used to create it. My transform stream doesn't even have access to the source stream (after all, not all sources *are* streams), so I can't check to see if an encoding has been set on it.  Conversely, when I receive a string, I get an encoding I don't know what to do with.

Unfortunately, neither [digging through the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/stream.html) nor searching the web have been very enlightening. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with your question, maybe it's just me but is the core issue that you want to know the encoding of a buffer? If so: fair and unfortunately this is probably not possible because it *is* just a sequence of bytes. Does the confusion come from the argument of `Buffer.toString()' ? because all that argument really does is take the series of bytes and convert them *from* whatever encoding they have to the standard javascript encoding.

Comment: @Evert Most of my confusion is that when my `transform()` method gets handed a `Buffer` (which could be encoded text), I have no way to know what encoding might have been used; but when it gets handed a string (which is *not* encoded), I'm given an "encoding" which I don't know what it corresponds to.